# self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow returns nil

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm fairly new to Objective-C and have encountered this following issue.

I've setup the storyboard and the linked up the view controllers accordingly. Also, setup the segue. However, for some weird reason, `self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow` is returning me `nil`.

Really appreciate for the help in advanced!

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"infoTherapyCloseCase"])
    {
        infoTherapyPhaseCloseCaseViewController *info = [segue destinationViewController];

        //info = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; 
        int row = [myIndexPath row];

        TherapyPhases *tp = _DetailModal[row];

        info.DetailModal = @[tp];
    }
}
```

Comment: One of two reasons: 1) `self.tableView` is `nil`. or 2) The table view has no selected row.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt reply. However, I do not quite get you. I have several tableview controllers working in the same way.. But unfortunately, I wasn't able to get this tableview controller to work the same way..

For some reason, [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];  returns me nil.

Comment: I've done a simple if self.tableview == nil and it return me false. How do I determine if the table has no selected row? Currently in my tableview cell I've got 3 buttons. For each button clicked, it will direct the user to another view controller

Comment: If a table has no selected row then the `indexPathForSelectedRow` returns `nil`. So you already know that your table has no selected row.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Is there anyway for me to trigger the correct value indexpathforselection when the user clicks on the button that is inside? I've done the same for the other tableview controllers and they had no issues. Not too sure what went wrong for this?